# rootstock current state

Tags: rootstock

currently i am leading a benchmark between the smartcontracts platforms, and i am exploring the **Rootstock** platform.

I think this project has a lack of documentation. My question is what is the current state of this project? I've learned they've launched the GINGER TESTNET recently.

is there any relevant post or documentation about this project and about its recent news. If there is a post explaining the deployment of a smartcontract on the testnet it will be very helpfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've contacted the Rootstock they provided me the following link https://github.com/RSKsmart/rskj/wiki

which provide a wiki for :

[Install RskJ and join the RSK Ginger Testnet](https://github.com/RSKsmart/rskj/wiki/Install-RskJ-and-join-the-RSK-Ginger-Testnet)

[Compile and run a RSK node locally](https://github.com/RSKsmart/rskj/wiki/Compile-and-run-a-RSK-node-locally)

[Getting started with Smart Contracts development](https://github.com/RSKsmart/rskj/wiki/Starting-with-RSK-Smart)

[Convert your Testnet Bitcoins to Ginger Smart Bitcoins and viceversa](https://github.com/RSKsmart/rskj/wiki/Convert-your-Testnet-Bitcoins-to-Ginger-Smart-Bitcoins-and-viceversa)

Besides there is a blog listing all the news : http://media.rsk.co/